# Definition of a geometric realization of a simplicial space.

Tags: algebraic-topology, geometric-realization

I am a little confused with the definition of a geometric realization. I follow "geometric realization of a simplicial topological spaces" link on ncatlab. It says that $|X|=\coprod_n X_n\times \Delta^n$ quotient out by the following relation: $(x,f_*(p))\sim (f^*(x),p)$ for each $f:[k]\rightarrow [l]$. I guess $f_*:\Delta^k \rightarrow \Delta^{k+1}$ is the inclusion of a k-face. Then what is the $f_*:\Delta^{k+1} \rightarrow \Delta^{k}$ ? Is it simply the linear projection to the k-face so that a chosen vertex maps to the center of a k-face?

Comment: It sounds like you perhaps don't understand the definition of a simplicial space (or simplicial set) and should start there instead.

Comment: @EricWofsey roughly speaking, simplicial space is a collection of topological spaces $\{X_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ together with bunch of maps between $X_k$ and $X_{k+1}$ satisfying conditions of naturality.

Comment: Let's take a simple case when all $X_n$ are discrete, so we are basically gluing different $\Delta_n$. How should I think of $f_*$ then?

Comment: @EricWofsey could you suggest any source ?

Comment: Notice that while $f_*$ is a map on the $\Delta^n,$ $f^*$ is a map between the $X_n.$ It seems like you're looking for both $f_*$ and $f^*$ to be maps between the $\Delta^n.$

Comment: @Stahl I don't think that $f_*$ and $f^*$ are both maps between $\Delta^n$.           $f^*$ is provided in the definition of a simplicial space $X$ but I wasn't sure about $f_*$. I know that $f$ is generated by face and degeneracy operators so to take the quotient space it is enough to consider the generators of an equivalence relation. I assumed I knew what are the face maps from $\Delta^n$ and $\Delta^{n+1}$ but I didn't know what are the degeneracy maps which go the other way.

Comment: http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2008/REUPapers/Allegretti.pdf at page 8 I have found exactly what I was looking for: $\sigma_i$.